# Allow user to save before session ends

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to alert user that the session is about to expire and let them save session data, if the user sees the alert If he happens to click the alert box the session refreshes. but if the user i snot around and gets back after a while I want him to see the session expired page and not pop up or on click of pop up redirect session expire page.
Code below is what I tried, I am pretty new to javascript and web application and stuck. Please guide me. thank you in advance

```
  function timeTicker() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime = 30) {
            resetTimer;
            window.clearInterval(timerId);
        }

        if (idleTime == 28) {
            window.alert("You have been idle for over 28 mins; your session will expire in next 2 mins, Please save any unsaved data.");

        }

    }

    function resetTimer() {
        idleTime = 0;
    }

    var timerId = window.setInterval(timeTicker, 60000);
    var idleTime = 0;
    var closeWindow = false;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    //document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert()` blocks execution. You'll need to use a non-blocking message like a div positioned in the middle of the page with css or a jQuery dialog.

Also, you have an error in your code:

`if (idleTime = 30) {` is assigning 30 to `idleTime`. You need `if (idleTime == 30) {`, though I would probably change it to `if (idleTime >= 30) {`.

I also think you need to redirect and log off the user if the idleTime is 30 or more, not clear the timer interval.

Answer (score 0):

Only the user can close the alert dialog after it has been opened. If hiding the alert message after session expiration is a requirement, then your alert message has to be displayed in some other way besides an alert dialog. For example, you could use jQuery UI to create a pop-over dialog message containing the alert message. You would be able to close the pop-over and display a Session Expired message once the full tiemout period is elapsed.